# updated xcode for ios5 app wont run stops at __dyld__dyld_start

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2

on Thread 1 
get initial start screen
then app pauses and all i get is 0 16_*dyld*_dyld_start

I updated to xcode 4.2 on lion (and it is the lion version) now it wont run my app which runs fine on prev xcode. I ran some test basic apps and they run fine.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: ok I found this fantastic mans answer that fixed my issue here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790848/iphone-simulators-crash-on-app-launch/7440432#7440432

phew!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To summarise the [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790848/iphone-simulators-crash-on-app-launch/7440432#7440432):

you change `-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` to `-weak-lSystem`

Did the trick for me too. Seems to still work on iOS 4 devices too.

(Changed to community wiki since it's not my answer.)

Comment: You sir, just saved my day. Been scratching my head for hours on this one.

Comment: I've just run into this same issue today — all worked fine before, but now my app hangs on launch with either this symptom or a SIGABRT (with no exception).  Sounds like the thing everybody is saying -weak_library fixes... but where do I set that?  I can't find any -weak_library setting in build or target settings, or anywhere else in the project.

Comment: Thanks — turns out that wasn't the culprit for me, which is why I couldn't find it in my project.  In my case, it was [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748425/xcode-4-2-sigabrt-error/9435143#9435143).