# XCode 5 Issue signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have searched through Google for over 2 hours now so I'm going to ask for some help here. I have a Single-View application that is getting this error whenever I click a button or navigation button. First it crashes the app then highlights three lines of code that I haven't even touched throughout the whole project, and it said

```
"Thread 1: signal SIGABRT", the 3 errors of code are this 0x1f6c952:  jae    0x1f6c962                 ; __pthread_kill + 26`,      `0x22ef9b:  xorl   %eax, %eax`, and `        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

No idea what this means because I've never come across this error before. Could someone please help me.

Comment: Apply break point And see in which class and at which line this error comes.

Comment: this may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748425/xcode-4-2-sigabrt-error.

Comment: I added the breakpoint to the line of code `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));` And then I ran the application and it then said "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"

Comment: What are the three lines of code that it highlights?

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Is Xcode crashing or is your app? Because your title says "Xcode", but it sounds like you're talking about your own app.

Comment: Whenever you get the crash, log mentions "Reason". Are you sure you copy pasted the "Reason" part of your log? To get the info about Reason, you need to remove the breakpoint.

Comment: Guys The reason in the log is "-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8db3b20"

Answer (score -1):

Try these,

If this is happening on the simulator, restart your computer. If this is happening on a real device, restart the device, and if the problem persists, restart the computer as well. This problem has occurred for me multiple times, because of a zombified process left on the device/simulator when a test is unexpectedly aborted. A simple reboot will fix it.

**EDIT:**

If above instructions doesn't help, probably issue is within your project itself. Most common reason for this kind of error is, your app might trying to connect to an IBOutlet which doesn't exist. Did you delete any control from your storyboard without disconnecting it's IBOutlet from the code?

Comment: What a load of rubbish.  None of that will stop a crash.  I would be turning computers on and off all day long if it did work!

Comment: Guys The reason in the log is "-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8db3b20"