# sigabrt error when changing the title of a button in Xcode 9 swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a screen with a UIImage and a UIButton on it. I wrote code so that when the button is clicked the image changes and it worked. Then I wanted to add code to make the title of the button as well. After I added that code the program crashes with a sigabrt error. I checked the connections and everything look fine. How would I change the text/title  of a button without having it crash.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mapImage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //mapButton.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBAction func mapButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if x == true
    {
        mapImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "map")
        x = false
        mapButton.setTitle("1st Floor Map", for: .normal)
    }
    else
    {
        mapImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "School Map 2015-2016-2")
        mapButton.setTitle("2nd Floor Map", for: .normal)
        x = true
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 var x:Bool = true;
```

[Connection tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNjFV.png)

Comment: Please add the error log

Comment: Use debug mode, set breakpoint

Comment: This might be related to your use of image literals, and the possibility that they’re not in the main bundle. Try replacing these with `mapImage.image = UIImage(named: “1st Floor Map”)`. Other possibility is a duplicate (broken) connection in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `mapButtonTapped(_ sender:)`, you can change

```
mapButton.setTitle("2nd Floor Map", for: .normal)
```

to

```
sender.setTitle("2nd Floor Map", for: .normal)
```

`sender` here is the button which you tapped, and you had chosen the type to UIButton, you can access its properties as UIBUtton.

About the sigabrt error, you should try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748425/xcode-4-2-sigabrt-error).

Comment: This solved the problem. Why does sender work instead of mapButton though? Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: I think the problem is by your mapButton linked to storyboard (duplicate or the missing connection may be). In this case, they are the same.

Comment: Wouldn't there be an "!" next to the connection if it was a duplicate or an empty circle if it was missing? I didn't see either. I added a picture.

Comment: Open both of your storyboard and viewController in Assistant Editor mode, if the circle before `@IBOutlet weak var mapButton: UIButton!` is empty, means you missed the connection.

Comment: I don't see any empty circles