# setCompletionBlock: causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS only in simulator..it works fine on device

Tags: ios5, asihttprequest, exc-bad-access, asiformdatarequest

In the simulator, using ASIHTTPRequest's setCompletionBlock: message always causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Even setting NSZombieEnabled to YES does nothing to illuminate the situation.

```
__weak ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
        int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
        NSLog(@"%d",statusCode);
          }];

 [request setFailedBlock:^{  
        // send statuscode error back
        int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
        NSLog(@"%d",statusCode);
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after spending 2 days, I finally found the solution: Fixing my linker flags

Essentially you have to change -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib to -weak-lSystem.

I had originally added this because Urban Airship required it.

Many thanks to following References:

[EXC_BAD_ACCESS when copying or retaining Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111541/exc-bad-access-when-copying-or-retaining-block/7115171#7115171)

[iPhone simulators crash on app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790848/iphone-simulators-crash-on-app-launch)